# element by id with two points not reconized

Tags: cypress

When I search for an element by id, for example cy.get ('# billing: firstname') I get an error

```
//Firstname
cy.get('#billing:firstname')
.type('NameTest1', {force: true})
.should('have.value', 'NameTest1')
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use in this way:

> cy.get('#billing\:city').select('SAN-SALVADOR');